# I neet to convert date value into date/time value in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a cell with 07/26/13 and I want a formula to take this date each day it is updated and convert it to 07/26/13 00:00, so that I can make a formula in another cell with a time reference of IF between 00:00-02:00 on 07/26/13 to put a 1 in. How do I make the cell have both 07/26/13 00:00 when the cell that updates each day only has the date?

Comment: Can you please break up your question to better show what you're asking. Right now your question isn't very clear

Answer (score 1):

Is the cell with 07/26/13 considered as a date or as text by Excel? Because if it is considered a date, it already contains a time of 00:00, even if it might not be shown.

To test this you can get the hour/minutes from the cell by HOUR(A1) and MINUTE(A1), A1 being the cell obviously. If it's a legit date you'll get 0 and if it's not you'll get a #VALUE! error.

If the cell is not considered a date by Excel, one way to convert it is to extract the raw numbers using MID:

```
=MID(A1,1,2) gives "07"
=MID(A1,4,2) gives "26"
=MID(A1,7,2) gives "13"
```

And putting it all back together as a legitimate excel date:

```
=DATE(2000 + MID(A1,7,2), MID(A1,1,2), MID(A1,42))
```

This date may show as 2013-07-26, but if you apply the HOUR/MINUTE functions on it you'll see that it contains a 00:00 timestamp.